# "Use ambient noise reduction" option is gone in Catalina

Tags: macos-catalina

macOS Catalina removed the toggle "Use ambient noise reduction" and turned it on by default.

I read on other sites that this is a bug, but until the toggle returns, does anybody know if there is a `defaults write` for turning the noise reduction off?

[image: "Use ambient noise reduction" option]

Comment: Can you locate a file called com.applesound.pref.plist in your user folder under Library/Preferences and in the /Library/Preferences directory too? Open them (in read-only mode, even TextEdit will do, as they're XML files), and see if you find a reference to noise cancellation, and what the value reads. Should be a boolean.

Comment: EDIT to my previous post (I timed-out on editing...)  I found a gold mine here (https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.macos) for those who like to tinker, thanks to this article: https://eclecticlight.co/2019/08/15/global-defaults-in-macos-mojave/

Comment: EDIT to my EDIT: you could try one of those too... (Audio settings) /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist and /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.SystemSettings.plist.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find anything on these files, but if anyone has Mojave and could list the content on those in order to compare, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this setting is enabled by default in macOS Catalina, but I still hear noise. My best solution was to buy a USB/audio hub. It was cheap.

[image: USB Audio hub]

I compared the files from Gsazraetr response, and only found a difference in lines 50-55 of `com.apple.audio.SystemSettings.plist`, which was missing the segment below in the "Reduction On" version:

```
<dict>
    <key>master data source value</key>
    <integer>1769173099</integer>
    <key>uid</key>
    <string>AppleHDAEngineOutput:1F,3,0,1,1:0</string>
</dict>
```

But this file did not exist in my Catalina anyway.